# Why does Spray error "could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller"?

Tags: spray, spray-json

I use a `spray-json` for convert some case class into json, but i have  a troubles with convert List to json:

```
case class Foo(id: Int)

object FooJsonSupport extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
  implicit val fooFormats = jsonFormat1(Foo)
}

//and i have a list with Foo:
val list = List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))

// and i want to return json response

post {
  respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
    complete(list)
  }
}
```

After I run the sample, I get the error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller[scala.collection.immutable.List[Post]]

How to fix it?

Comment: have you imported content of FooJsonSupport? Like `import FooJsonSupport._`

Comment: Can you try the sample with `import akka.http.marshallers.sprayjson._` before `complete(list)`? I also think you should `import FooJsonSupport._` to bring the implicit `fooFormats` into scope.